eccentric to linear
How does one translate the up and down distance moved in degrees when rotating around an eccentric bearing
eg 10 degrees will get me X in a linear value


Given the angle $\theta$ which I'll define as between the up on the vertical and the line from the static center to the moving center of the eccentric. And the distance $d$ between the centers of the eccentric.
The vertical offset of the eccentric is equal to $d \cos \theta$
Getting the difference between positions is then basic arithmetic: $\Delta d = d \cos \theta - d \cos (\theta + \Delta \theta)$
